# I want to create a command that will compute fine for specific person

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a command that will compute for overdue books but I want it in specific person only.
My command is to insert fine in the table Borrowbook. I also put the codes in the button where datagridview will show data.
My code is like this:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT  [Student ID], ISBN, Title, Date, [Due Date], Penalty FROM    Borrowbook;", con);


        try
        {
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            DataTable Records = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(Records);
            BindingSource bsource = new BindingSource();

            bsource.DataSource = Records;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bsource;
            sda.Update(Records);


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        if (dateTimePicker2.Value < DateTime.Now)
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Borrowbook (Penalty) VALUES  (@Penalty)";
            SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("@Penalty", SqlDbType.Int);
            p1.Value = 50;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p1);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command to UPDATE the borrow record (it is already present in the table) with the fine should include the Student ID and the ISBN of the books with overdue return

```
  cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Borrowbook SET Penalty = @Penalty " + 
                    "WHERE [Student ID] = @stuid AND ISBN = @isbn";
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Penalty", 50);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stuid", GetStudentID());
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isbn", GetISBN());
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Of course you need to extract the values for the parameter Student ID and the ISBN from your grid (I suppose from the current selected row)

For example

```
 public int GetStudentID()
 {
     // The Student ID is the first cell of the current row
     int Row = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;
     return Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1[0,Row].Value);
 }

 public string GetISBN()
 {
     // The ISBN is the second cell of the current row
     int Row = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;
     return dataGridView1[1,Row].Value.ToString();
 }
```

In my example above I have used the [AddWithValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx) method to add the parameters and their values to the command object. This method is handy because you could do everything with one line of code, but be aware that AddWithValue decides the datatype of the parameter by looking at the datatype of the value passed in. If your database field and your parameter don't match you could get errors or incorrect conversions. Also AddWithValue is less performant than an explicit declaration of the parameter and its datatype. [Look at this very detailed article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236412.aspx) for a deeper understanding of parameter passing

Comment: It is fine now but the other error is has blue underline and it says. Cannot implicity convert type 'string' to 'int'

Comment: Sorry a copy/paste error not noticed. GetISBN should return a string (Supposing the database field is of datatype text)

Comment: you mean I will change the return dataGridView1 to return Convert.ToString?

Comment: Look at your database table BorrowBook. Is the field ISBN a text datatype (nvarchar, varchar etc...)? If yes you need to pass a parameter @isbn with a string value to AddWithValue. Otherwise you could get errors in updating your data. AddWithValue is handy, but you need to be rigorous on the parameter that you pass because it determines the datatype implicitly from the value you pass

Comment: I have an error on return Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1[0, Row].Value); it says that 'Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.' My database field on student ID is int.

Comment: Probably you don't have any value in the currentRow for the student id cell or you don't have a row selected. The code above is just a base code to follow. You need to make it more robust adding error checking based on the behalf you expect your user will follow. Add if(dataGridView1.CurrentRow != null) and other checks before reading the grid